# Do all Spike and Suzy stories contain fantastical or science fictional elements?

Tags: spike-and-suzy

The Flemish comics series *Suske en Wiske* by Studio Vandersteen is known in the UK as *Spike and Suzy* and in the USA as *Willy and Wanda*.

Most stories I've read contain science fictional elements (often by way of Professor Barabas and his Teletime Machine) or fantastical elements (such as recurring character Sus Antigoon, a ghost). Often both.

**Is there any story that contains neither?**

Or do all Spike and Suzy stories contain *some* fantastical or science fictional elements?

---

*Of course, Jerommeke's super strength is fantastical in and of itself, so I'd like to ignore that for the purpose of this question, or at least treat it separately from other elements.*

Comment: I've had a quick look at a representative sample. Even those with little discernible reason for scifi/fantasy content seem to invariably have a character who's magic or a fantastic formula that allows you to speak to animals, etc etc

Comment: @Valorum I'm currently looking into _Sjeik el Rojenbiet_ (I don't know if it has been translated into English). From memory, the most fantastic part of that is Jerome squeezing water out of a stone.

Comment: I've found a trove of translated comics. Of the twenty plus I've looked at, they all have fantasy elements. The least fantastical is one where they try to stop a poacher. They take a potion which appears to render them capable of understanding the speech of animals.

Comment: OK, so Suske en Wiske is now formally scifi and fantasy. Oh well.

Comment: @MrLister not necessarily, but quite a bit of it *is*. If you disagree, you could ask on meta about the topicality of the series.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "De rammelende rally" and "Het sprekende testament" don't contain any, but that's from memory, so I'd have to double-check.

Comment: @DonFusili didn't "Het Sprekende Testament" have Lambik using a protective talisman?

Comment: @SQB Right, the one they got in Japan earlier, good thing I was only pretty sure ;-)